# There was no error when using 3 joints, but I want to know why the simulation cannot be implemented using 2 joints

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to make a planar RR manipulator through gazebo. So I used the code and executed it, but the error below occurs. There was no error when the simulation was implemented with three joints, but when the simulation was implemented with two joints, the following errors occur.

## urdf code:

```
<link name="link0">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="1.5" radius="0.75"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="1.5" radius="0.75"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="1.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
</link>

<link name="link1"> 
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.0 2.5 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="1 6 1"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>


    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.0 2.5 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="1 6 1"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 2.5 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="1.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
</link>

<link name="link2">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="1.5" radius="0.75"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="1.5" radius="0.75"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="1.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
</link>

<link name="link3"> 
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0.0 -2.5 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="1 6 1"/>
        </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0.0 -2.5 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="1 6 1"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0.0 -2.5 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <mass value="1.0"/>
        <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
    </inertial>
</link>

<joint name="world_fixed" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.75" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="link0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint1" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link0"/>
    <child link="link1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit velocity="50.0" effort="10" lower="-1.5" upper="1.5" />
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 6 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link1"/>
    <child link="link2"/>
    <limit velocity="50.0" effort="10" lower="-1.5" upper="1.5" />
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="joint2" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0 6 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link2"/>
    <child link="link3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit velocity="50.0" effort="10" lower="-1.5" upper="1.5" />
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
</joint>

<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="joint1">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-1.5</param>
            <param name="max">1.5</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="joint2">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-1.5</param>
            <param name="max">1.5</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
    </joint>


<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros2_control" filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so">
        <robot_sim_type>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</robot_sim_type>
        <parameters>/home/domin/gazebo_ws/install/robot_description/share/robot_description/config/simple_robot_controller.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

## error:

[ERROR] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process has died [pid 14167, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher /home/domin/gazebo_ws/install/robot_description/share/robot_description/urdf/simple_robot.urdf --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_16onpqaw'].
[gzclient   -2] ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.

There was no error when the simulation was implemented with three joints, but when the simulation was implemented with two joints, the following errors occur.